# Filtering out rows with NA in list

Tags: filter, na

I am preparing code in order to upload an excel file with multiple sheets in order to separate them into their own excel files for easy upload. In order to do so I used the following code to create the list of dataframes.

```
   sheet_names <- excel_sheets("data.xlsx")
   list_all <- lapply(sheet_names, function(x) {
     as.data.frame(read_xlsx("data.xlsx", sheet = x, range = "K2:M200")) } )

   names(list_all) <- sheet_names
```

The above code successfully uploaded each and every sheet (146 of them) into their own DF which has the below format in an example:

```
   Date_Time       Depth      Pressure
   2022-01-09      65         70
   2022-08-09      65         NA
   2023-01-09      65         68
   2023-08-09      65         69
```

My goal is to remove all of the Rows from every DF with NA in the **Pressure column**

I have tried to use the following code:

```
   lapply(list_all, Filter, Pressure = Negate(is.na))
```

But I keep on getting the unused argument error.

I have also tried to use:

```
  apply(list_all, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Even though I get no errors from this code, it does not remove the rows with NA.